# Linking dynamically generated links to php, by passing session id for each link

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

i have this code in item.php:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
$link .= '<br><a href="item.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">'.$row['item_name'].'</a><br>';
}

echo $link;
```

so this generates links based on how many result there are (in the database), so say a user has 4 items, it will display item names as hyperlinks, but im not sure how i would go about linking this to my itemdetail.php. so each item will link to itemdetail.php, but they will have unique information that will be taken from mysql database.

at the moment i would just like itemdetail.php to echo the item name, but what i want just for now is, i would like generate a unique session id for each link based on the item_id, so when i press it the session id is passed to itemdetail.php and from there i can pass session id as string and pull data from mysql (the easy bit, so dont need help in this bit).

i know how to pass sessions id from page to page, but that's only for fixed links (buttons that already exist), but i cant figure out how to do this for generated buttons/links.

FYI, my url does show /item.php?id=12345, 12345 being my item_id, if that helps. this is when i click on the generated links (so from /item.php to /item.php?id=12345 or whatever the item_id is for each link), but of course apart from changing the url, the links do nothing else.

tl;dr create a unique id for each generated link (easiest way probably to get item_id and use that), pass unique id as a session, then echo session in another php.

thanks in advance for any helpful insights.

itemdetail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php'); 
echo $_SESSION['advert'];
$aName = $_SESSION['advert'];
?>
```

atm nothing happens because, the buttons in item.php don't connect to this. if i try:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
$link .= '<br><a href="item.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">'.$row['item_name'].'</a><br>';
if($link == true) {
 header("Location:item.php");
}
```

i get 'headers already sent by' error

Answer (score 1):

To access the item ID if you pass it like you are right now, use something like `$_REQUEST['id']`.

IF you are actually asking about session IDs (which are not the same as your application-level item IDs show in the question):

Session IDs are usually passed via cookies.

PHP will do this for you natively without significant application code. You just need to call `session_start()` and the user's session data will be available in the `$_SESSION` global.

Under the hood, this works by having the server pass a session ID to the client via a set-cookie header, and the client's browser will the hand it back attached to all future requests to the same server. On the server side, the session ID is connected to a data store (files on the local filesystem, by default, but can be a database or whatever depending on your PHP config).

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve.

If you want the page `item.php` to display a list of items if no `id` is specified, then just have an `if ($_REQUEST['id'])` to separate the two cases. (Be careful when handling input!)

If the item id is not enough to identify an item uniquely (which it SHOULD), then add the other info to the url as well:

```
$link .= '<br><a href="item.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'&sid='.session_id().'">'.$row['item_name'].'</a><br>';
```

If you have problems with using `session_id()` directly, you can do two things:

1. Call `session_id()` before headers are sent and store the id in a variable.
   `$SID = session_id()` or something like that.
2. Buffer the output until the very end. See [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

If, however, you want the items in the displayed list to have the same identifier but be different based on the user viewing them, you will have to give a little bit more details.

Your logic in `item.php?id=N` could be adjusted to consider `$SID` and turn a received id `N` into the `unique id` of the item used in the database. Entirely depends on your particular application...

You could also use the `$_SESSION` array that php conveniently maintains for you. When you generate the links, store the needed info (the `unique item id` for example) there. Then the next time you load `item.php?id=1` you can access `$_SESSION['item_links'][$n]`.

Again, I didn't quite understand what you were asking.